# How to refresh the tkinter Listbox

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

The objective: I select an option in the list box. I wish to highlight the option with yellow color.

The problem: All the previously selected options are also highlighted yellow. I wish to just retain the newest selection as yellow, and everything else in the list box as white.

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
fontfamily = tk.font.families()

def selectcolor(col=None):
    fontlist.config(bg='white') ##<--PROBLEM CODE
    option_selected = fontlist.curselection()
    fontlist.itemconfig(option_selected[0], bg='yellow')

fontlist = tk.Listbox (root, bg='white')
fontlist.grid()

for eachfont in fontfamily:
    fontlist.insert(tk.END, eachfont)

fontlist.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', selectcolor)
##<<ListboxSelect>> is magic, this option is not shown in_
##ebook John Shipman tkinter 8.5 reference
##.curselection() doesn't work as expected

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think that by doing `fontlist.config(bg='white')` you're trying to set the background color of the `Listbox` and not of its items. You could for example keep track of the last selected item and color it white before coloring the new selected item with yellow.  The problem is that since the color of the selected item is only visible (at least in my case) after the item loses focus, then you'll never seen a yellow-colored item...I hope someone comes out with another smart solution...

Comment: Thanks @nbro. I added code as below inside the selectcolor(), doesn't still seem to work.     size=fontlist.size()
    while size:
        fontlist.itemconfig(size-1,bg='white')
        size-=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `selectbackground` option for the `ListBox` object. You don't need to use `fontlist.config(bg='white')` row. And the solution is like that:

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
fontfamily = tk.font.families()

def selectcolor(col=None):
    fontlist.config(bg='white') ##unnecessary
    option_selected = fontlist.curselection()
    fontlist.itemconfig(option_selected[0], selectbackground='yellow')

fontlist = tk.Listbox (root, bg='white')
fontlist.grid()

for eachfont in fontfamily:
    fontlist.insert(tk.END, eachfont)

fontlist.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', selectcolor)
##<<ListboxSelect>> is magic, this option is not shown in_
##ebook John Shipman tkinter 8.5 reference
##.curselection() doesn't work as expected

tk.mainloop()
```

I have edited codes due to problem of querent.

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
fontfamily = tk.font.families()


#you don't need to define a function to change highlight color.


fontlist = tk.Listbox (root, bg='white', selectbackground='yellow') #add selectbackground='yellow' here.
fontlist.grid()

for eachfont in fontfamily:
    fontlist.insert(tk.END, eachfont)

#So it is necessary to bind a function now :)

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: I can't upvote you due to my newbie status. I am getting greedy now, changing goal post here. I have three list boxes to choose font family,size and weight. Your solution 'un-highlights' the selection color (i.e loses yellow selection) when the focus moves from the current list box to another list box. Is there a way to retain the yellow highlight after moving to a different list box?

Comment: You can find your new solution above. I have extended may answer.

Answer (score 0):

Previous items keep their yellow background because you do not change them back (which would require remembering the last item marked).  But it is much easier is to use the selectbackground option.  Is anything wrong with the following for your purpose?

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
box = tk.Listbox(selectforeground='black', selectbackground='yellow')
box.pack()
box.insert('end', 'one', 'two', 'three')
#root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I can't upvote you due to my newbie status. I am getting greedy now, changing goal post here. I have three list boxes to choose font family,size and weight. Your solution 'un-highlights' the selection color (i.e loses yellow selection) when the focus moves from the current list box to another list box. Is there a way to retain the yellow highlight after moving to a different list box?

Comment: Possibility 1: revert to using itemconfig, with the addition of reverting the background of the previous selection, as I suggested above.  This is what tk does by default, unless you change the 'selectmode' option.

Comment: Possibility 2: combine a Button, Label, or Entry with a ListBox or drop-down Menu.  Note that ttk.Combobox combines an Entry and drop-down menu.

Comment: Possibility 3. Simulate a Listbox with a read-only but clickable  Text.  This would be the hardest, but I know it would work because IDLE edit windows do not loose color highlights when not active.  One could even put all three columns in one text box.